# How to get image uri which is saved in server folder?

Tags: java, mysql, image, url, server

My requirement is need to get image location as url, we are providing services to Android app in that app need to display images where images are  stored in server, we need to send image location as uri to app, I had search in Google but I did not get relevant information .

I didn't have much experience in in this technologies, I have recently started working on services.

I am using Tomcat7 as a server, MySQL as database using Java restful web services.

**Note**: image need to be send as URL because it is easy to displaying in app.

Comment: pleaase put comment if anything is wrong in question , i am new to this technology and SO

Comment: _i am new to this technology and SO..._ Take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to directly access any resource it should be present in server container. 
In your case it is webapps folder in tomcat server directory.Say Image is present in **/webapp/images/xyz.jpg**

So suppose you have domain name **http://mytomcatserver.com** pointing to your server.

Then uri will be **http://mytomcatserver.com/images/xyz.jpg**

Comment: thanks for reply, can i place more than 30 images in that folder

Comment: Server is just like your system . So it will depend on memory of that System. Just difference is you have one specific URL to point root folder i.e http://mytomcatserver.com afterwards you can have any folder structure or any number of files inside it.